# trouble resetting forgotten password in recovery mode, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: password-recovery

I beleive I have followed correct procedures to reset my password in recovery mode.
However my new password is not accepted. I still cannot access my OS.
It appears to have set a password for recovery mode, but not my main access.

Comment: Have a look at our answer to the following question or link to our website to see if you have done everything right http://askubuntu.com/questions/181840/installation-password/181846#181846 - http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/resetpassword.html - hope it helps .  :o)

Comment: I personally prefer to boot from a live CD/DVD/USB and do a `chroot` then use `passwd` to change password.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with my password and I tried everyone's suggestions but none worked for me. So I tried some of my own and this is what worked for me... "Keep in mind I can NOT explain why it worked, all I know is it worked...

**"10 Easy and Simple steps to Reset Lost or Forgotten Password"**

1. Reboot computer and hold the Left Shift Key down.
2. Select boot into recovery mode.

   [image: http://i.imgur.com/yWK0N0m.png]
3. After a few seconds you should get the "Recovery Mode Options" screen.

   [image: http://i.imgur.com/g812F2o.jpg]

   **Note:** (Here is the part I can't explain. After trying everything, and nothing working, I finally just started trying all the options here one at a time. When I tried the `"grub Update grub boot loader"` and then followed the rest of the steps all was well and password was reset.)

   So before going to the `"root Drop to root shell promt"`selection,
4. Select `"grub Update grub boot loader"`, and you should get this screen.

   [image: i.imgur.com/cctcZyx.png]
5. Select `"Yes"`. Wait for it to go through the update.
6. Now select `"root Drop to root shell prompt"`.
7. Now you should be at a root terminal with something like the following: `youracctname@yourcompname:~$.` type `passwd accountname` ( acountname  being the name of the account you are trying to change the password for ).
8. `Enter new Unix password:` "enter the new password".
9. `Retype new Unix password:` "retype the same password you did in Step-8".
10. It should confirm successful password change. type `exit` at the prompt and reboot.

If this does not work for you, try skipping Steps 4 & 5...